# Why would a data studio connector suddenly become "unknown" and stop working?

Tags: looker-studio

I've been using the GKE Usage Metering connector for a couple of weeks now, with no trouble.  Today suddenly anyone that accesses the reports that use it (including me!) gets errors.. If I go into the connector settings and try to reconnect, I get

```
Unknown Connector
By Unknown
A description is not available for this connector.

It is your responsibility to review and comply with all applicable third party TOS.
 Attention: This connector has not been verified or reviewed. It is recommended that you only use community connectors from trusted sources.

There was an error retrieving this Add-on's configuration.
```

With a refresh authorization button that does nothing I can see.  Every data source that uses this connector suddenly started doing this.  If I try to add a new one, I see the connector, but it keeps telling me my bigquery dataset is using the wrong format for the name, despite the fact that it's not.  How can I refresh whatever needs refreshing to get it to reconnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/153716969) for the GKE Usage Metering connector. Follow the linked bug for updates from the GKE team. In the meantime, the connector is not usable.